# Why I'm getting different light data properties?

Tags: lighting, properties

Why I'm getting different light data properties and how can I switch between them? I'm using Blender 3.2.1. Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends if you are in Eevee (left picture) or Cycles render engine (right hand picture)

Comment: Ah, Thanks! And how can I change the Custome Distance (Cycles)?

Comment: the option doesn's seem to exist in Cycles

Comment: Thanks, just wanted to know if I'm missing something.